# Received data buffer always empty after calling socket's ReceiveAsync() call?

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, windows-phone-8

I have a Windows Phone 8 app that talks to server over a socket.  The server is quite simple.  It accepts a string, returns a string, and immediately closes the connection.  I have talked to the server using Windows Forms apps and never had a problem.

I'm using the code below which I adapted from this MSDN page that shows how to use a socket in a Windows Phone 8 app:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202858(v=vs.105).aspx

I modified the code to be non-blocking using async/await.  All of the methods are awaitable now and the WaitOne() call after each socket async operation is spun off to a new task.  I am not getting any socket errors or Exceptions.  However, when the anonymous Completed event handler for the ReceiveAsync() call fires, the bytes transferred value is always 0.

*Strange note.  If I set a breakpoint on certain lines in completed event handler for ReceiveAsync() the call times out.  This doesn't happen if I don't set a breakpoint and it only happens on certain lines.  I have no idea why.  No time-outs occur if I don't set breakpoints*

What am I doing wrong?  Here's the code I'm using.  The calling code (not shown) simply creates an instance of the SocketDetails class, and then calls in order, *await ConnectAsync()*, *await SendAsync("somestring")*, and finally *await ReceiveAsync()* on the SocketDetails instance.:

```
/// <summary>
/// Details object that holds a socket.
/// </summary>
public class SocketDetails
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new socket details object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hostName">The host name for the connection.</param>
    /// <param name="portNumber">The port name for the connection.</param>
    /// <param name="timeOutMS">The maximum number of milliseconds to wait for a connection before <br />
    ///  timing out.</param>
    /// <param name="defaultBufferSize">The maximum number of bytes for the buffer that receives the <br />
    ///  connection result string.</param>
    public SocketDetails(
        string hostName,
        int portNumber,
        int timeOutMS,
        int defaultBufferSize)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(hostName))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("The host name is empty.");

        if (portNumber <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("The port number is less than or equal to 0.");

        if (timeOutMS < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("The time-out value is negative.");

        this.HostName = hostName;
        this.PortNumber = portNumber;
        this.TimeOutMS = timeOutMS;

        // Create DnsEndPoint. The hostName and port are passed in to this method.
        this.HostEntry = new DnsEndPoint(this.HostName, this.PortNumber);

        // Create a stream-based, TCP socket using the InterNetwork Address Family. 
        this.Socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        // Create the manual reset event.
        this.ClientDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The string returned by the last connection attempt.
    /// </summary>
    public string ConnectionResult { get; private set; }

    public DnsEndPoint HostEntry
    { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The host name to open the socket on.
    /// </summary>
    public string HostName { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The port number to use when opening the socket.
    /// </summary>
    public int PortNumber { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Cached Socket object that will be used by each call for the lifetime of this class
    /// </summary>
    public Socket Socket { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Signaling object used to notify when an asynchronous operation is completed.  Exposing it <br />
    ///  so other threads/code can reset it if necessary, unblocking any threads waiting on this socket.
    /// </summary>
    public ManualResetEvent ClientDone { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Define a timeout in milliseconds for each asynchronous call. If a response is not received within this <br />
    //   timeout period, the call is aborted.
    /// </summary>
    public int TimeOutMS { get; set; }

    // The maximum size of the data buffer to use with the asynchronous socket methods
    public int BufferSize { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Waits until a socket operation completes or the time-out period is reached.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>TRUE if the semaphore wait did not TIME-OUT, FALSE if a time-out did occur.</returns>
    private bool BlockUntilSocketOperationCompletes(string caller)
    {

        // Sets the state of the event to nonsignaled, causing this task's thread to block.
        // The completed handler of the socket method that called this method should unblock it.
        this.ClientDone.Reset();

        bool bRet = this.ClientDone.WaitOne(this.TimeOutMS);

        if (bRet)
            Debug.WriteLine("WaitOne() completed successfully for caller: " + caller);
        else
            Debug.WriteLine("WaitOne() timed-out for caller: " + caller);

        return bRet;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// (awaitable) Connects to the socket using the details given in the constructor.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Returns the banner or error message returned from the sockete during the <br />
    ///  connection attempt.</returns>
    ///  <remarks>This call BLOCKS until the connection succeeds or the time-out limit is reached!</remarks>
    async public Task<string> ConnectAsync()
    {
        // Create a SocketAsyncEventArgs object to be used in the connection request
        SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        socketEventArg.RemoteEndPoint = this.HostEntry;

        // Inline event handler for the Completed event.
        // Note: This event handler was implemented inline in order to make this method self-contained.
        socketEventArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(delegate(object s, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
        {
            // Retrieve the result of this request
            this.ConnectionResult = e.SocketError.ToString();

            Debug.WriteLine("CONNECT completed, Connection result string received: " + this.ConnectionResult);

            // Signal that the request is complete, unblocking the UI thread
            this.ClientDone.Set();
        });

        // Make an asynchronous Connect request over the socket
        this.Socket.ConnectAsync(socketEventArg);

        // Wait for the return operation to complete or until it times out.
        bool bIsTimeOut = !(await Task.Run(() => BlockUntilSocketOperationCompletes("ConnectAsync")));

        return this.ConnectionResult;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// (awaitable) Send the given data to the server using the established connection
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data">The data to send to the server</param>
    /// <returns>The result of the Send request</returns>
    /// <remarks>This call BLOCKS until the data is received or the attempt times out!</remarks>
    async public Task<string> SendAsync(string data)
    {
        string response = "Operation Timeout";

        // We are re-using the _socket object initialized in the Connect method
        if (this.Socket != null)
        {
            // Create SocketAsyncEventArgs context object
            SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();

            // Set properties on context object
            socketEventArg.RemoteEndPoint = this.Socket.RemoteEndPoint;
            socketEventArg.UserToken = null;

            // Inline event handler for the Completed event.
            // Note: This event handler was implemented inline in order 
            // to make this method self-contained.
            socketEventArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(delegate(object s, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
            {
                response = e.SocketError.ToString();

                Debug.WriteLine("SEND completed, Response received: " + response);

                // Unblock the UI thread
                this.ClientDone.Set();
            });

            // Add the data to be sent into the buffer
            byte[] payload = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
            socketEventArg.SetBuffer(payload, 0, payload.Length);

            // Make an asynchronous Send request over the socket
            this.Socket.SendAsync(socketEventArg);

            // Wait for the return operation to complete or until it times out.
            bool bIsTimeOut = !(await Task.Run(() => BlockUntilSocketOperationCompletes("SendAsync")));
        }
        else
        {
            response = "Socket is not initialized";
        }

        return response;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// (awaitable) Receive data from the server using the established socket connection
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The data received from the server</returns>
    async public Task<string> ReceiveAsync()
    {
        string response = "Operation Timeout";

        // We are receiving over an established socket connection
        if (this.Socket != null)
        {
            // Create SocketAsyncEventArgs context object
            SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
            socketEventArg.RemoteEndPoint = this.Socket.RemoteEndPoint;

            // Setup the buffer to receive the data
            socketEventArg.SetBuffer(new Byte[this.BufferSize], 0, this.BufferSize);

            // Inline event handler for the Completed event.
            // Note: This even handler was implemented inline in order to make 
            // this method self-contained.
            socketEventArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(delegate(object s, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("RECEIVE completed.");

                if (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success)
                {
                    // Retrieve the data from the buffer
                    response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Buffer, e.Offset, e.BytesTransferred);
                    response = response.Trim('\0');

                    Debug.WriteLine("RECEIVE completed, response received: " + response);
                }
                else
                {
                    response = e.SocketError.ToString();

                    Debug.WriteLine("RECEIVE failed: socket error: " + response);
                }

                this.ClientDone.Set();
            });

            // Make an asynchronous Receive request over the socket
            this.Socket.ReceiveAsync(socketEventArg);

            bool bIsTimeOut = await Task.Run(() => BlockUntilSocketOperationCompletes("ReceiveAsync"));
        }
        else
        {
            response = "Socket is not initialized";
        }

        return response;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Closes the Socket connection and releases all associated resources
    /// </summary>
    public void Close()
    {
        if (this.Socket != null)
        {
            this.Socket.Close();
        }
    }
} // public class SocketDetails
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I strongly recommend you not use TCP/IP. If at all possible, use WebAPI + HttpClient instead. This is particularly true if you are still learning `async`.

That said, my comments follow.

Receiving an empty array is a normal situation for a socket. It indicates that the other side has closed down its sending channel.

I don't recommend using the `SocketAsyncEventArgs`-based API. It's [possible, but awkward](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/12/15/10248293.aspx) to make it work with `async`. Instead, <s>write [TAP-over-APM wrappers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#ApmToTap) (I prefer to write these as extension methods)</s> use the TAP methods (the ones defined on `SocketTaskExtensions`).

The `*Async` wrappers in your code sample all follow a pattern where they start an asynchronous operation and then queue up a thread pool operation to wait for it to complete. This seems quite unnecessary to me; `Task<T>.Factory.FromAsync` or `TaskCompletionSource<T>` would be more efficient and less convoluted.

Finally, you should ensure you are not using a read-then-write loop, a common mistake with TCP/IP applications. There are a couple of problems with a read-then-write loop; one of them is that it cannot recover from the [half-open problem](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html), which I describe on my blog.

Comment: Thanks Stephen.  I'll rewrite my code.  Is there a document or video series that can greatly accelerate my async learning?

Comment: I'm not sure if you've seen [my `async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html). I list a few good references at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks. I find the async concept easy to grasp, but the dizzying array of creating tasks and the nuances of each style to be a problem.  (Task.Run, Task.Factory.StartNew, new Task().Run, etc.)

Comment: There's a lot of holdovers from parallel tasks, which should not be used in the `async` world. For `async`, it boils down to two options: CPU-bound work uses `Task.Run`, and everything else uses `TaskCompletionSource` or one of its shortcuts (usually `Task.Factory.FromAsync`).

Comment: Wow. One of the most enlightening facts I've read about async, buried in an SO comment. I hope others find it.  That explains *a lot* of my confusion.  I thought parallel tasks and async/await were one and the same.  Thanks!

Comment: What do you do if a method you want to use with FromAsync() does not return IAsyncResult?  In this case, [socket].ConnectAsync()?

Comment: It is possible to wrap anything using `TaskCompletionSource<T>` ([including `ConnectAsync`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/12/15/10248293.aspx)), but in that case wrapping `BeginConnect`/`EndConnect` in `FromAsync` would be easier.

Comment: Pardon me if I'm just being dense, but that was what I first tried and couldn't find a BeginConnect/EndConnect method pair attached to the type Socket in Windows Phone 8.

Comment: That could be; I'm not familiar with `Socket` on WP8.

Comment: @StephenCleary after more than 6 years, would you like to revise your answer? I think it deserves some updates!

Comment: @Leonardo: Done.